# How does the PIC knows a keyboards is a keyboard and should be mapped to IRQ #1?

Tags: assembly, operating-system, hardware, interrupt, interrupt-handling

I've read in an article from OSDev Wiki than the IRQ #1 matches keyboard. But how does PIC know a keyboard is a keyboard, and then it should be mapped to IRQ #1?

Comment: Each 8259 PIC (or the hardware that emulates the behavior of 2 PICs) has the equivalent of 8 input lines on each PIC. The keyboard interrupt is tied to the Master pic on input line 1. The PICS are set by BIOS or Hardware to map to PC interrupt vectors starting at vector 0x08 (Master IRQ0 to IRQ7) and 0x70 (Slave IRQ 08 to IRQ15). The PICs don't know what is tied to each input pin. It is up to the processor(CPU) to query the PIC for the source of the interrupt and then call the right interrupt vector (routine)

Comment: The base vector of 0x08 (Master) and 0x70(slave) can be reprogrammed by sending a command to each of the PIC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The PIC doesn't know about this at all.  It just triggers an IRQ 1 if it gets a signal on its IRQ 1 pin.  This pin is connected to the keyboard controller on the mainboard, so when the keyboard controller issues an interrupt it is received by the PIC. Of course in modern PC compatibles, all these wires are part of a highly integrated super IO chip and not actually visible to the naked eye.

So to answer your question: the PIC knows because there is a wire from the keyboard controller to the PIC.

Answer (score -1):

On systems with BIOS and USB the BIOS contains a USB keyboard driver that runs in System Management Mode and feeds keyboard events to the keyboard interface thereby simulating a physical PS2 keyboard.

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question as posed.